# lxml parser browsing directory for html files

Tags: python-3.x, directory, pycharm, lxml

I am working with this code:

```
import lxml.etree as et
import os
import glob

import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()


def skip_to(fle, line):
        with open(fle) as f:
            pos = 0
            cur_line = f.readline().strip()
            while not cur_line.startswith(line):
                pos = f.tell()
                cur_line = f.readline()
            f.seek(pos)
            return et.parse(f)


def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"F:\ABC")
    with stdout2file("Test123.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('**\*.html', recursive=True):
            xml = skip_to(file, "<?xml")
            tree = xml.getroot()
            nsmap = {"ix": tree.nsmap["ix"]}
            fractions = xml.xpath("//ix:nonFraction[contains(@name, 'ABC')]", namespaces=nsmap)
            for fraction in fractions:
                print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                print(fraction.get("name"), end="| ")
                print(fraction.text, end="|" "\n")
                break
trade_spider()
```

and I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/lxmlparser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/lxmlparser.py", line 42, in <module>
    trade_spider()
  File "C:/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/lxmlparser.py", line 33, in trade_spider
    xml = skip_to(file, "<?xml")
  File "C:/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/lxmlparser.py", line 26, in skip_to
    return et.parse(f)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:79720)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1803, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116182)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1823, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116474)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1718, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115235)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1139, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:110109)
  File "parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103323)
  File "parser.pxi", line 679, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:104936)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 324, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:10656)
  File "parser.pxi", line 362, in lxml.etree._FileReaderContext.copyToBuffer (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100828)
  File "C:\6930p\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1789: character maps to <undefined>
```

For the following, my directory consists of 5 subfolders each containing up to 12 subfolders filled with HTML files.
The Code works perfectly if I set `os.chdir(r"F:\ABC\201X\XXX")` to each subfolder in directory '201X'. However it will give me the above mentioned error message IF:
1. I set `os.chdir as r"F:\ABC\2012\October` (October is the first subfolder in subfolder 2012 that the lxml parser is parsing. (For ALL other subfolders this works however perfectly!?)
2. If I set `os.chdir as r"F:\ABC`. As I don't want to set all subfolders manually my initial intention has to be parsing all subfolders in ABC automatically. I thought if I use `for file in glob.iglob('**/*.html', recursive=True):` it would browse all subfolders containing in my directory "ABC"?

Anyone have encountered an issue like that before?

Comment: Try,    `with open(fle,encoding="utf=8") as f`

Comment: Again thank you very much @PadraicCunningham! It works perfectly on my first subfolder 'October' as well as on my subfolder '2012' for parsing all containing subfolders.

Comment: no worries,  you can add it as an answer to close the question.

Comment: So it's again me.... The code worked perfect for my first subfolder "2012" in "04_Independent...." and all it's containing subfolders "October, November, December". However I tested the code randomly on some other subfolders and it seems that it is not properly working for all. The code is executed but after that doesn't stop running. A txt output file is created but it is empty.... Any Idea what causes this problem? I haven't changed anything on the code except the utf=8 encoding. I don't get it, why it is working on some subfolders, but on some others not?!

Comment: P.S. I used my BS4 version as an alternative and it works properly through all subfolders without problems. But as I mentioned in my other post, BS4 is way to slow for parsing a huge amount of HTML files. It takes like forever to get the final txt output file....

Comment: add a link to some of the files that it does not work for and a couple of files that it does.

Comment: I will have a look later when I am free and give you a ping when I see what is happening

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your extensive help on that!

Comment: Is there somehting like a chat function at stackoverflow? Perhaps it would be more efficient to talk on a chat and I'll give a summary of what the problem was and how it was solved including the final code?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112708/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-florian-schramm).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Sorry for the late response, but now I have answered your question in the chat room.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham : Would you have the time to have a look at my example files I posted in the chat room?

Comment: I will have a look and let you know

Comment: I think I identified the problem. If I have HTML formatting like <span> classes inside my HTML text I get a "None" output. However if the HTML Text ends with <nonNumeric or <nonFraction it works perfect. I posted a new question on this, if you want to have a more detailed description. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508226/lxml-parser-struggling-with-span-elements-in-html-text

Comment: Which file is that in?

Comment: if you have a look at the dropbox link I posted in the chat, I uploaded a few files that are working properly and a few where i get a "None" output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding accounts for the the `UnicodeDecodeError` which is sorted by setting the encoding to *utf-8*, the issue with the code getting stuck in a loop is because not all your files have `"<?xml"`, some have `<html ...` the revised function will fix the issue, I also added some debugging so you can see what files contain no data.

```
import logging
import contextlib
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
logging.basicConfig(filename="debug.log")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)




@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w', encoding="utf-8")
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()

def skip_to(fle, starts):
        with open(fle) as f:
            pos = 0
            cur_line = f.readline().strip()
            while not cur_line.startswith(starts):
                pos = f.tell()
                cur_line = f.readline()
            f.seek(pos)
            return et.parse(f)

def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Independent Auditors Report")
    with stdout2file("auditfeesexpenses.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('./*.html'):
            xml = skip_to(file, ("<?xml","<html"))
            tree = xml.getroot()
            nsmap = {"ix": tree.nsmap["ix"]}
            fractions = xml.xpath("//ix:nonFraction[contains(@name, 'AuditFeesExpenses')]", namespaces=nsmap)
            for fraction in fractions:
                print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                print(fraction.get("name"), end="| ")
                print(fraction.text, end="|" "\n")
                break
            else:
                logger.debug("Nothing found in file {}".format(file))

trade_spider()
```

Comment: Perfect! This has been the solution for my problem! The only thing I changed was with open(fle, encoding="utf=8") as f: just so be sure that there is no utf-8 encoding anymore but everything else works pretty neat!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it has been an encoding issue. When changing `with open(fle) as f:` to `with open(fle,encoding="utf=8") as f` and therefore using utf-8 enconding it works without problems.

Comment: Furthermore, if not every single file has "<?xml" it goes into an infinite loop. Therefore the solution is to extend for xml = skip_to(file, ("<?xml","<html"))! Thanks again to Padraic Cunningham for this fast and easy response!

Comment: Also, if the tag you are searching for has child tags like <span> or anything else you need to substitute `print(fraction.text, end="|" "\n")` with `print(fraction.xpath(".//text()")[0], end="|" "\n")` to get all the text including the children.

Answer (score 0):

Final Code:

```
import lxml.etree as et
import os
import glob
import logging
import contextlib

logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
logging.basicConfig(filename="debug.log")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w', encoding="utf-8")
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()


def skip_to(fle, starts):
        with open(fle, encoding="utf=8") as f:
            pos = 0
            cur_line = f.readline().strip()
            while not cur_line.startswith(starts):
                pos = f.tell()
                cur_line = f.readline()
            f.seek(pos)
            return et.parse(f)


def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"F:\XYZ")
    with stdout2file("Test123.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('**/*.html'):                             
            xml = skip_to(file, ("<?xml", "<html"))
            tree = xml.getroot()
            nsmap = {"ix": tree.nsmap["ix"]}
            fractions = xml.xpath("//ix:nonNumeric[contains(@name, 'NAMEATTRIBUTE')]", namespaces=nsmap)
            for fraction in fractions:
                print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                print(fraction.get("name"), end="| ")
                print(fraction.xpath(".//text()")[0], end="|" "\n")
                break
            else:
                logger.debug("Nothing found in file {}".format(file))            
trade_spider()
```

With many thanks to @Padraic Cunningham!

Answer (score -1):

Hmm i got that kind of error when was working with the file in python 2 with Cyrillic symbols and made in python 3.

As i can see you also have similar 
May be this will help you
Type in the top of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```